# How to make a curve on a rectangle's top in css? only in top edge

Tags: css, geometry, curve, css-shapes

I want to create the following shape:
[image]

Important: if I use "Border Radius" I get this (and I do not want this result):
[image]

Comment: Use border radius, but make the block with border radius big enough so it looks like a circle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/gewok/1/edit)

HTML:

```
<div id="gray">
    <div id="red"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#gray{

  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;  
}

#red{

  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  background-color: #f00;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: -25%;
  right: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would be roughly equivalent:

http://jsfiddle.net/ny4Q9/

#### css:

```
.curvetop {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 80px;
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.curvetop:after {
    top: -80px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 170px;
}
```

#### markup:

```
<div class="curvetop"></div>
```

By using `border-radius` with a value of 50% you can create a circle.. which, as per your question you can attach to the top of another element by way of a pseudo element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use border radius

http://jsfiddle.net/wULyB/

```
<div id="out">
    <div id="in"></div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#out{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: green;
    position: relative;
}
#in{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
    top: 30px;
}
```

You can play around with the numbers but you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

In case you want the curve to be inward:

[image]

```css
body { margin:0 }

#out {
  width: 100%;
  height: 230px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(206deg, #FFCCB5 0%, #FE590F 80.02%);
  position: relative;
}

#in {
  width: 180%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  left: -45%;
  top: -150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="out">
    <div id="in"></div>
    
</div>
```