# Make wave borders in css

Tags: css

I'm trying to round borders in a proper way. So what i have now:

```css
#example1 {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 150px;
  border-top-left-radius: 145px 220px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 145px 220px;
}
```

```html
<div id="example1">
  <p>test.</p>
</div>
```

What i expect:
[image]

On the code result, the corners are to rounded at the edge, so how to make the corners  straighter like in the image?

Comment: like showing here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61627646/8620333 ?

Comment: or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764144/how-to-make-a-curve-on-a-rectangles-top-in-css-only-in-top-edge ?